# How to give an EFS directory path to s3 putObject using nodejs lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I am trying to put data from EFS to S3 using NodeJs lambda function. First of all I am zipping all the files on EFS and then moving that zipped file to S3. Here is my code:

```
export const lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        //file is going to be zipped here
        ZipLocal.sync.zip("/mnt/data").compress().save("/mnt/data/zipped.zip");
        console.log("files zipped");

        // File is going to be uploaded to s3

        const fileToUpload = "/mnt/data/zipped.zip";
        let bucketName = "matomo-lambda-test-bucket";
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: "zipped.zip",
            Body: fileToUpload,
            ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
        //await s3Client.putObject(params).promise();
        const s3Data = await s3Client.send(
              new PutObjectCommand(params)
            );
        console.log("Upload Completed", s3Data);
```

I don't know how to set Body that usually accepts object or string but in my case I want to give EFS zipped file path. How to do this?

Comment: There's nothing EFS specific about this. Once EFS is mounted it appears to your software as a local file system. Thus your code would be no different from accessing any local file.  See the "Uploading a File to an Amazon S3 Bucket" section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response. Can you please tell me one more thing? By following the guide shared by you, there is createReadStream function. When I am using it to copy data from EFS and upload it to the s3, it uploads very wierd data to s3. I want to  copy my actual zip file and upload it to s3. Can you tell me how I can sort it our?

Comment: That's just standard NodeJS file I/O. You should be testing this out locally, to test uploading a local file to S3 and make sure that works before even trying to deploy to Lambda.